# How to push file from android device to linux desktop?

Tags: android, linux, desktop

How to push/pull file from android device to linux desktop? I've created a lsmod log of my device, but unable to pull it from the device to the desktop of my linux distro.

Comment: `adb pull` did not work?

Comment: if using eclipse there is DDMS and "File Explorer"

Answer (score 0):

You can user adb to pull/push file from your android device to your PC viceversa using usb cable

Copy file from android device to PC

```
adb pull /sdcard/yourfile yourPC's location
```

Copy file from PC to android device

```
adb push filefromyourPC /sdcard/file
```

Answer (score 0):

You need "mtpfs" to do that. You should install it on your linux desktop. After installation, connect you android phone to your desktop and turn on file sharing over usb in phone.
After it, mount your phone's storage on a new directory on your linux.